# why $n$ is obviously nullhomotopics in $S^2?$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I  have some confusion about the statement in Allen hatcher Book

Page No:$33$

> **Theorem** $1.10:$ For  every contnious map $f:S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ there exist a pair of antipodal points  $x$ and $-x $ in $S^2$ with $f(x)=f(-x)$

In the theorem of the proof it is written that

> But $h$ was  the composition $gn: I \to S^2 \to S^1$ and $n$ **is obviously nullhomotopics** in
> $S^2$

Im  not getting  why $n$ **is obviously nullhomotopics** in $S^2?$

**My thinking** : For nullhomotopic  $X$ must be contractible

Since $S^2$ is not contractible $\implies$ a   map from $I \to S^2$
is not homotopic to a constant

Therefore  $n$ **is not  nullhomotopics** in $S^2$

Comment: What is $h,g,n,I?$

Comment: If $X$ is contractible, then every map is nullhomotopic. There are nullhomotopic maps to non-contractible spaces, for example, constant maps. In particular, your second last sentence is wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews see the [page no:33](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf)

Comment: If $I=[0,1]$ then any function $I\to S^2$ is null homotopic

Comment: @jasmine Questions here should try to be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: $\eta$ is just a loop around the equator, $(\cos \pi s , \sin \pi s, 0)$ with $0 \leq s \leq 1.$  It is the intersection of the sphere with the plane $z=0$ We can parametrize a contraction by demanding that $\eta_t (s) $ lie in the plane $ z \cos t + (x-1) \sin t =0,$  Given that you were asking about $\eta,$ I don't understand why you did not type in the (short) definition of $\eta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book, the assumption is that $\eta:[0,1]\to S^2$ a map with $\eta(0)=\eta(1)$ and $\eta$ maps out an equator. The assertion that $\eta$ is null homotopic is as a loop, not really as a map $[0,1]\to S^2.$

Intuitively: If you consider $\eta$ as a rubber band around the equator, you can slip the rubber band up and over one of the poles.

Rigorously, let $x\in S^2$ be a point not on the path of $\eta.$ Then we have a known homeomorphism $\phi:S^2\setminus \{x\}\cong \mathbb R^2.$ Then we can compose $\phi\circ\eta$ and show that $\phi\circ \eta$ is null homotopic because $\mathbb R^2$ is contractible. So we can pull back that homotopy to $S^2\setminus\{x\}$ and hence to $S^2,$ and get that $\eta$ is null homotopic.

This shows that all loops $\eta:[0,1]\to S^n$ which are not onto are null homotopic, for any $n.$ This is true for any loop for $n>1,$ but this technique does not prove the onto case, and it is not true for onto loops $[0,1]\to S^1.$